# LFO doesn't affect biquadfilter frequency

Tags: javascript, web-audio-api

I'm able to use an oscillator to modulate another oscillators frequency, or a gain nodes gain value... but when I connect to a biquadfilter frequency param nothing changes. Is this a bug?

https://jsbin.com/yurenexufe/edit?js,output

```
let ctx = new AudioContext()

let o = ctx.createOscillator()
let oGain = ctx.createGain()

let lfo = ctx.createOscillator()
lfo.type = 'sin'
lfo.frequency.value = 5

let lfoGain = ctx.createGain()

let hipass = ctx.createBiquadFilter()
hipass.type = 'highpass'
hipass.frequency.value = 3000

o.connect(oGain)

lfoGain.gain.value = 25

oGain.connect(hipass)

hipass.connect(ctx.destination)

o.type = 'square'

lfo.connect(lfoGain)
lfoGain.connect(hipass.frequency) // does nothing?
lfoGain.connect(o.frequency) // works

o.start()
lfo.start()
```

Answer (score 2):

Okay I needed WAY higher `gain` value on my lfo to hear the difference. changing it from `25` to `1000` I could hear it.